# Is it possible to obtain instance of component being resolved before satisfying property dependency?

Tags: castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

```
public class A
{
    public X x { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public X x { get; set; }
}

public class X
{
    public X(object owner) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Basically if classes `A` and `B` are registered in Windsor I want to be able to resolve `X` dependency in such a way that it gets instance of the class it was required for.

In plain code it would look like that:

```
var a = new A();
var x = new X(a);
a.X = x;
```

Is there a way to do this in Windsor, maybe through some extensibility mechanism?

---

It looks like some crazy question even for me, so here is some motivation behind it:

The `X` in the example above is `ITracer` which is a proxy for `TraceSource` that is adding some bits of info to each traced message, namely, unique ID of the owner and its type (now it is only ID - that's why the question - I can't get to the instance and call `GetType()` on it).

A brief example to make it more clear. Suppose you have some service `IService` and want to add traces to it in the most non-intrusive way. But in the application could be dozen of instances of this service, so in traces you want to distinguish them by ID/type. It would be good if class received its tracer from the container and just wrote messages there when needed, without thinking of IDs, concrete `TraceSource` etc.

I already have some infrastructure that allows me to write like that:

```
[TracedTo("NameOfTheTraceSource")]
public class Service : IService
{
    public ITracer Tracer { get; set; }
}
```

And Windsor correctly resolves `Tracer` to be its own (non-shared with other objects) instance of `ITracer` pointing to `TraceSource` with name `NameOfTheTraceSource`. Moreover, if I add `traceAllMethods = true` to the attribute - Windsor will automatically add interceptor which will write down each method call on this instance via the same `Tracer` (and only does this if corresponding `TraceSource` has some listeners configured - we don't have to support adding them on the fly). This is just awesome because it doesn't require *anything* from the developer of `Service` and it doesn't suffer performance degradation when it is not needed, not a bit. And so I'm working to make this even more convenient :)

Comment: I think a service override would work -- or maybe a sub-dependency resolver.  Have you looked at those?

Comment: @Patrick My current implementation is based on sub-resolver that is able to resolve instances of ITracer. Unfortunately, it has access only to ComponentModel instead of instance of component. Or maybe there's some trick I don't understand? Could you provide some basic code sketch please?

Comment: I've read this a few times and I'm not quite sure what exactly you need -- or what it is that isn't working.  Could you update the question with a code sample of how you've set up Windsor and what part isn't working.  Are you getting the wrong instance resolved?  What logic determines that the "right" instance of "owner" is for each "X"?

Comment: @Patrick, no I get everything as I expect. The problem is that I don't know if the thing I want *in addition to what I have already* is possible or not (and if possible - how). Basically I want to inspect every component `Z` being created: if it has property dependency on class `X` - then I want to provide it *after* `Z`'s instance `z` is created, and create `X` instance with `ctor(z)` call, i.e. to pass owner's instance to the dependency. ...It seems that explanation is even worse now :((

Comment: Actually, that clears things up.  I would create a factory and pass it to Z and let Z's ctor use it to initialize its "X" property.  Would that work?

Comment: @Patrick yeah, that would work at the cost of several additional lines on consumer's behalf. Still, good idea, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think what you want here is a facility.  Here's a simple one (with no error checking) that may be what you're looking for (or at least point you in the right direction):

```
public class XFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        this.Kernel.ComponentCreated += KernelOnComponentCreated;
    }

    private void KernelOnComponentCreated(ComponentModel model, object instance)
    {
        var props =
            instance.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite && p.PropertyType == typeof (X));
        if (props.Any())
        {
            var pi = props.First();
            pi.SetValue(instance, new X(instance), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Now make sure you add the facility to the container before you do any resolving:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<XFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<A>(),
                    Component.For<B>()
    );

var a = container.Resolve<A>();
```